# ResponseEntity<> должен вернуть несколько объектов. Как это осуществить?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Необходимо вернуть детали по id продукта и их количество. Прошу оценить код.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/details")
public class DetailRestControllerV1 {

private final DetailService detailService;

public DetailRestControllerV1(DetailService detailService) {
    this.detailService = detailService;
}
@GetMapping("/byproduct/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<DetailsAndDetailsCountContainer> getDetailsByProduct(@PathVariable("id") Long productId) {
    if (productId == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    List<Detail> details = detailService.findDetailsByProductId(productId);

    if (details.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    int countDetails = details.size();

    DetailsAndDetailsCountContainer container = new DetailsAndDetailsCountContainer();
    container.setDetails(details);
    container.setCountDetails(countDetails);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(container, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

}

Сам объект

```
@Data
public class DetailsAndDetailsCountContainer {
  private List<Detail> details;
  private int countDetails;
}
```

Насколько правильное это решение и есть ли альтернативы?

Comment: Вы изобрели обычный wrapper, что является правильным и достаточно стандартным подходом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если на другой стороне полноценный JSON парсер (Java, JavaScript, TypeScript...), то можно возвращать `ResponseEntity<List<Detail>>`, список на той стороне десериализуется в список или массив, в зависимости от языка, а у него будет длина.

---

Альтернатива

```
public class DataList<T> {
  private List<T> items;
  private int count;

  DataList(List<T> items) {
    this.items = items;
    this.count = items.size();
  }
}

ResponseEntity<DataList<Detail>> getDetailsByProduct(...) {
  ...
  return new ResponseEntity<>(new DataList(details), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```